# word to syllable converter

Tags: c++, nlp, linguistics

I am writing a piece of code in c++ where in  i need a word to syllable converter is there any open source standard algorithm available or any other links which can help me build one.

```
for a word like invisible syllable would be in-viz-uh-ble
```

it should be ideally be able to even parse complex words like "invisible".

I already found a link for algorithm in perl and python but i want to know if any library is available in c++

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the application behind ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible for english language without a dictionary. The english language has lost it's 1-to-1 mapping between spelling and pronounciation to the degree that the even the number of syllables aren't apperant from the spelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example shows a phonetic representation of the word, not simply a split into syllables. This is a complex NLP issue.

Take a look at [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) and [metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone). There are C/C++ implementation for both.

Also many dictionaries provide the [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) notation of words. Take a look a Wiktionary API.

Comment: Soundex and metaphone are hashing algorithms, they don't do transcription.

Comment: Technically they are both rough phonetic transcriptions. Very destructive with soundex, more preservative with metaphone. Both more or less discards vowels, so I admit it may not be interesting depending on how the OP use them.

Comment: You may want to investigate my [double_metaphone](https://github.com/pixelglow/double_metaphone) implementation in C++11. It has a callback parameter which allows you to recover the original vowels or tag individual parts of the original word, which roughly approximates the syllables.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting syllables in words, you could adapt a project of mine to your needs.
It's called [tinyhyphenator](http://tiny-hyphenator.sourceforge.net/).

It gives you an integer list of all possible hyphenation indices within a word. For German it renders quite exactly. You would have to obtain the index list and insert the hyphens yourself.

By "adapt" I mean adding the specification of English syllables. Take a look at the source code, it is supposed to be quite self explanatory.